# React Refs are null after rerender

Tags: javascript, reactjs, blazor-webassembly

I'm new to React and I have the following react components that I'm using in a Blazor WASM App.

```
// Parent
export class Parent extends React.Component{
  
  constructor(props){
     super(props);
     this.childRef = React.createRef();
     
     // saving reference to component to access it using Blazor JS Interop
     window.canvasComponentRef = this
  }

  render(){
     return <Child ref={this.childRef} />
  }

  parentFoo = () => {
     this.childRef.current.foo();
  }
}

// Child
export class Child extends React.Component{
   constructor(props){
     super(props);
   }

  render(){
     return <div> Content </div>
  }

  foo(){
    // some actions in child
  }
}
```

I render the component using...

```
ReactDOM.render(Parent, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**Result**: childRef.current work

When the user navigates away from the Parent component page, I unmount it manually using...

```
ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(document.getElementById('root'));
```

When the user comes back to the Parent component page, I render it again using...

```
ReactDOM.render(Parent, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Now, when I call window.canvasComponentRef.parentFoo(), childRef.current is null.

Can anyone explain why?

Thank you!

Comment: Why are you manually unmounting a component?

Comment: I noticed that when I navigate away from the Parent component page, the Parent component is not unmounted (componentWillUnmount() is not called). When I navigate back to it, it behaves weird and freezes (I was feeling like a new instance of the parent component is created again)

Answer (score 0):

My issue was actually the global variable at

```
// saving reference to component to access it using Blazor JS Interop
 window.canvasComponentRef = this
```

After refactoring it to get a ref to the Parent component using callback refs as below, the issue got resolved.

```
let parentRef = null;

function handleRef(element){
   parentRef = element;
}

function renderParent(){
   const parent = <Parent ref={this.handleRef}/>
   ReactDOM.render(parent, document.getElementById('root'));
}

// Now call parent method like below:
function callParentFoo(){
   parentRef.parentFoo();
}
```